# How to store google authenticated user profile picture in firebase android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

How to put user default profile picture(who is authenticated with google) into firebase storage?

```
private StorageReference stRef; 
private DatabaseReference userDb; 
private FirebaseAuth mAuth; 

Users users1 = new Users(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName(),mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail()
                                                ,mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(),
                                                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()),studyDetails,mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl());
                                        userDb.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(users1);
```

this has failed to store in database

Comment: Your question is not clear, what do you want exactly ? Put your code if you have any issue to help you.

Comment: i want to display all user image who are using my application.How to do it?.Say user are authenticated with google account.

Comment: The default image from auth providers ? Like google, facebook ?

Comment: yes Pipiks the default one i wanna show.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38844210/7277557 this worked thanks

Comment: So close the question or validate answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//while storing user details

Users users1 = new Users(
  mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName(),
  mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail(),
  mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(),
  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()), studyDetails, mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl().toString()
);
userDb.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(users1);

//While Retriving user datials

holder.txtName.setText(users.getsUserName());
holder.txtEmial.setText(users.getsEmailId());
holder.txtJoined.setText("Joined on: " + users.getsDateJoined());
Uri uri = Uri.parse(users.getPhotoUri());
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(uri)
  .transform(new CircleTransform())
  .resize(150, 150)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(holder.imageView);
```

Comment: this worked fine. I converted uri into string before storing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can access to the user picture with :

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

if (user != null) {
    Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();
}
```

[Here the auth user documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_a_users_profile)

Then you can use a lib like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to display it.

Set user picture :

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("photoUrl").setValue(photoUrl);
```

Retrieve other user picture :

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).child("photoUrl").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String photoUrl = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

[Here the realtime database documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Comment: ya this works for only current user. But how about other users using my application.

Comment: String photoUrl = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue(); //String photoUrl or Uri photoUrl

Comment: You just have to `Uri url = Uri.parse(photoUrl)`